# May I ask an author if he now knows the answer to their dormant question?

Tags: support, answers

Is it allowable to use the "answers" section to ask an author if he has found a solution to his question (which was posted months ago but only received one reply) but hasn't posted it?

If not is there any other way to contact an author of a question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the answers section for anything except answers is not looked upon favorably.

You may contact them by [commenting on their post](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).  Such a query is perfectly acceptable for a comment.

You must earn at least 50 reputation before you are allowed to comment on any posts except your own.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Sadly I haven't reached the reputation threshold for that yet so it looks like I'll need to find some questions that I know the answers to!